# PHP chr() returns diamond question mark from HTML

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding

I've read a lot on this subject, since it's quite a popular problem, but I can't find a solution...

I have an HTML with form in it...

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  ?>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   <input type="password" name="pass">
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

...from which I get the password through $_POST global and afterwards want to split into an array of ascii values, each of which will be changed with standard arithmetic functions (+ / - / * ...) and afterwards get from those changed numbers a character from ascii table with ord function...

```
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$password = str_split($password);
foreach($password as $letter) {
 $letter = ord($letter);
 ..do some algorithmic stuff to the number I get..
 $letter = chr($letter);
}
$password = implode('', $password);
```

...final step - put it into mysql...

```
mysql_query('update some_table set password="'.$password.'" where some_value=something');
```

Problem? No matter how I try to split the string up (str_split, substr, mb_substr, preg_split, str_replace - explode etc) I ALWAYS get the same result which is chr(53) (symbol which is displayed when displaying a character that can't be interpreted as UTF-8) for every symbol in both database and output in browser and it doesn't even matter if I'm using special characters or something exclusive to UTF-8. I've only really tested it with standard english chars. Note that:

- I have put accept charset as UTF-8 in form
- I'm sending headers through PHP saying this is UTF-8
- I've put in meta tags in HTML head to tell the browser this is UTF-8
- I'm using mb_internal_encoding to do everything as with UTF-8
- I am saving my .php files as UTF-8 without BOM
- The password field in mysql is utf-8_general_ci
- Connection to database is set to UTF-8

I'm desperate right now. I'm fairly sure there's something really embarassingly simple that I've missed, but please help...

## EDIT

I switched places of ord() and chr() function calls as they were intended. I had previously made a mistake and the point was to get ascii value(int) and afterwards convert the number to a character of corresponding value in ascii table.

Comment: You can't set the headers after you've started outputting stuff in the response body - you're also trying to assert UTF-8 in the header but declare iso-8859-1 in the meta - which is it?

Comment: if string is in utf-8 you should use mb functions. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: Are you using the to 'encrypt' your passwords?

Comment: Your string operation is nonsense. `chr` on a string is nonsense. `/* some algorithmic stuff */` is nonsense on the result of `chr`. `chr(53)` is not the Unicode replacement character. You're simply screwing up your string by processing it with nonsensical operations. What's the point of this to begin with?

Comment: @deceze I edited my code. I hope this makes more sense to you now. And the point is to encrypt passwords at least somewhat.

Comment: @Emissary -that was yet another mistake. It was supposed to be UTF-8 (didn't have time to go through my post twice). Sorry guys.

Comment: "Encrypt at least somewhat"...?! Why are you rolling your own "somewhat" encryption scheme? You either *hash* passwords, for which there are great functions available, or you *really* encrypt passwords, for which there are great functions available.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, look on the definition of these functions:

```
string chr(int)
int ord(string)
```

And you are using chr() on a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you intended to do what this code will do?

```
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$password_letters = str_split($password);
$new_password_letters = array();
foreach($password_letters as $letter) {
    $letter_code = ord($letter);
    $letter_code++; // or do your algorithmic stuff to the number you get..
    $new_letter = chr($letter_code);
    $new_password_letters[] = $new_letter;
}
$new_password = implode('', $new_password_letters);
```

Comment: I suppose this is the best answer to a question that makes no sense... Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for wasting your time with this terrible question. For three days I looked for an answer, but missed my own error. Encoding had nothing to do with this, and I was simply asking the chr() function to display a character with a value that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

@Criss
You have another mistake.
Not only you confused ord() and chr().
But you miss the point that $letter is actually a copy of array element which is to be processed in current loop iteration, not an element of $password array itself. 
So this code

```
foreach($password as $letter) {
 $letter = ord($letter);
 ..do some algorithmic stuff to the number I get..
 $letter = chr($letter);
}
```

won't make any changes to $password. You should fill another array in the loop, or use foreach in such manner:

```
foreach ($password as $i => $letter) {
    $password[$i] = your_function($letter);
}
```

May I ask you to vote for my answers? I'm a newcomer here and can't even comment with near-zero reputation.